# autocompletion netbeans javascript gmaps / here

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, netbeans-7

I use netbeans to develop a software in java.
To use different types of maps (here maps, gmaps ...) we have to work with their javascript API.

In order to load this API, I use this code in HTML :

```
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But netbeans do not have this file in local so it cannot help me with the autocomplete.

How to have this autocompletion even if the file comes from the web ?

Thanks in advance !